# Java Regex only upper case and numbers with predefined format

Tags: java, regex

I have problem with my Java regex. I am testing it here (https://regex101.com/) and  it looks like I am not good with regex :(

Regex should look like this:
TR12H4-030-485

1. TR12H4-> Only upper case and numbers plus characters allowed. 6 chars long
2. 030-> only numbers. 3 chars long
3. 485-> Only numbers. 3 chars long
4. Should be like XXXXXX-XXX-XXX with minus

Can someone give me good hints? Thank you

Comment: `Only upper case` ... the first component in your example has a lowercase `h` in it.  Please clarify the rules.

Comment: Also he claims the Regex should look like this. In that case, that's the regex.

Comment: Sorry. Updated. Typo error.  XXXXXX-XXX-XXX it means that after 6 chars minus is mandatory. etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution with every step explained

### TR12H4-> Only upper case and numbers plus characters allowed. 6 chars long

Use `[A-Z0-9]{6}`, this means use letters from `A` to `Z` but also all digits 6 times

### 030-> only numbers. 3 chars long

Find 3 digits one after the other : `\d{3}`

### 485-> Only numbers. 3 chars long

Same as above : `\d{3}`

### Should be like XXXXXX-XXX-XXX with minus

Now use them together : [`[A-Z0-9]{6}-\d{3}-\d{3}`](https://regex101.com/r/F5oKwR/1)

Comment: @user16320675 sorry it was a problem with a copy pate I think